# Reading file to char** using fgets and memcpy

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to read a set of lines from a file to an array. I'm doing this to learn malloc and realloc.

```
#define MAX_LINE 301

char** read_file_lines(char* filename) {
    char** ptr = NULL;
    int max = 5;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fp != NULL) {
        char line[MAX_LINE];
        while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE, fp) != NULL) {

            /* allocate some extra memory for some more lines */
            if(i == max) {
                int new_max = max * 2;
                int nr_bytes = new_max * sizeof(char) * MAX_LINE;
                char **ptr2 = realloc(ptr, nr_bytes);
                if(ptr2 != NULL) {
                    ptr = ptr2;
                    ptr2 = NULL;
                    max = new_max;
                }
            }

            // ptr[i] = line;
            // strcpy(ptr[i], line);
            memcpy(ptr[i], line, strlen(line));
            i++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error opening file %s\n", filename);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

The code compiles. However, when it is executed, an error occurs (the program crashes).

I did some debugging and determined that the problem is in up in the `memcpy ()` instruction. I had previously tried using `strcpy`, which also gives a similar problem.

I went to check memcpy ()'s protocolo and it is as followS:

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

Now, if `ptr` is `char**`, isn't `ptr[i]` equivalent to a `char*` ?

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `ptr` isn't initialized to point to any memory at all. Also, you're not allocating any memory for the individual lines.

To initialize `ptr`, change the declaration to:

```
int max = 5;
char** ptr = malloc(max * sizeof(char*));
```

Try adding this before the call to memcpy:

```
        ptr[i] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
```

and change the calculation for the `realloc` call:

```
            int nr_bytes = new_max * sizeof(char*);
```

**EDIT:** To explain in more detail: `ptr` is a pointer to an array of pointers. You have to allocate memory for `ptr` (that is, enough memory just to store individual pointers). *In addition to this*, you also have to allocate each individual array of characters that the individual elements of `ptr` will point to.

The first change I suggested ensures that `ptr` always points to enough memory to hold 5 pointers (or more, once it's been realloc'd.)

The second change ensures that each member of `ptr` always points to valid memory before you try to access it as a pointer.

And the third change is required because `ptr` points to elements that are *pointers* to `char`, not `char`.

Comment: Thanks. I have one question, regarding the 3rd change: should it not be coherent with the first malloc? I.e., do I need to multiply x * MAX_LINE ? If so, why?

Comment: D'oh! Yeah, MAX_LINE doesn't need to be in that calculation. I'll edit the answer in a sec.

Comment: Thanks. I'm setting this as the complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that at first execution memory is not allocated: `i` is 0, `max` is 5, the `if` condition is false and the `realloc` is never executed.

Comment: Yeah, thats one of the problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nah. Arrays are not pointers. Pointers to pointers are not arrays of arrays. If you want a two-dimensional dynamic array, then you have to allocate memory for 1. the array of pointers that point to the individual lines, and 2. for the lines themselves too.

Comment: +1. Thanks for point that out. I was under the impression that it was equivalent, because I remember reading somewhere that int main (int argc, char* argv[]) and int main (int argc, char** argv) are equivalent. But, apparently, that is only true in function declarations.

Comment: @MyNameIsZero When passed to functions, the first (innermost) dimension of an array *decays into* a pointer. This doesn't mean that arrays are pointers.

Comment: But isn't the same of the array a pointer to its first element? And arrays can be manipulated using "pointer arithmetic". Its kind of confusing.

Comment: Thanks. There's a whole chapter on the subject. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html